# Qibla compass is not correct or not accurate

Tags: android

first get north of the current location , 
then compute the bearing ,

here is the code :

```
  @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
float azimuth = (int)event.values[0];
            azimuth =  azimuth * 180 / (float) Math.PI;
GeomagneticField geoField = new GeomagneticField(Double.valueOf(
                    location.getLatitude()).floatValue(), Double.valueOf(
                    location.getLongitude()).floatValue(), Double.valueOf(
                    location.getAltitude()).floatValue(),
                    System.currentTimeMillis());

            azimuth += geoField.getDeclination(); // converts magnetic north
                                                    // into true north
            float bearing = location.bearingTo(MeccaLocation); // (it's already
                                                                // in degrees)

float Meccadirection = (float) (azimuth - bearing);
}
```

but the result direction is not accurate.

Comment: By not accurate, do you mean it is pointing in the correct direction but it is off by a few degrees sometimes? If so, perhaps the "180" is causing some rounding problems. Try instead to use "180f". So "azimuth =  azimuth * 180f / (float) Math.PI;"

Comment: sometimes yes with small diff. , but sometimes big diff   i tried to put 180f the same thing ,